# Scrapy login to redirected site using Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, scrapy, web-crawler, scrapy-splash

I'm trying to login to the following site: http://go.galegroup.com.proxy-um.researchport.umd.edu/ps/eToc.do?docId=0PQC&userGroupName=umd_um&action=DO_BROWSE_ETOC&inPS=true&prodId=GVRL&etocId=GALE%7CCX2830999001&isDownLoadOptionDisabled=true. This initially sends me to a redirect page which appears to use Javascript to redirect. I was unable to get Scrapy to follow the redirect here so I'm now using splash-scrapy to redirect to the login page. Currently I am able to get to the login page but when I try to use `scrapy.FormRequest.from_response` the response I get is not the correct page.

My Scrapy program:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest

class DbioSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'dbio'
    start_urls = ['http://go.galegroup.com.proxy-um.researchport.umd.edu/ps/eToc.do?docId=0PQC&userGroupName=umd_um&action=DO_BROWSE_ETOC&inPS=true&prodId=GVRL&etocId=GALE%7CCX2830999001&isDownLoadOptionDisabled=true']

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield SplashRequest(url, self.parse, endpoint='render.html', args={'wait': 0.5})

    def parse(self, response):
        with open('login.html', 'w') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
        return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(response, formdata={'username': '???', 'password': '???'},
                                                callback=self.after_login)

    def after_login(self, response):
        with open('after_login.html', 'w') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
```

Output from Scrapy:

```
2017-10-14 09:13:32 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.4.0 started (bot: bio)
2017-10-14 09:13:32 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'bio.spiders', 'DUPEFILTER_CLASS': 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareDupeFilter', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['bio.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'bio', 'EDITOR': 'emacs', 'HTTPCACHE_STORAGE': 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareFSCacheStorage'}
2017-10-14 09:13:32 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats']
2017-10-14 09:13:32 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2017-10-14 09:13:32 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy_splash.SplashDeduplicateArgsMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2017-10-14 09:13:32 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2017-10-14 09:13:32 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2017-10-14 09:13:32 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-10-14 09:13:32 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2017-10-14 09:13:33 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://go.galegroup.com.proxy-um.researchport.umd.edu/ps/eToc.do?docId=0PQC&userGroupName=umd_um&action=DO_BROWSE_ETOC&inPS=true&prodId=GVRL&etocId=GALE%7CCX2830999001&isDownLoadOptionDisabled=true via http://192.168.1.7:8050/render.html> (referer: None)
2017-10-14 09:13:33 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.searchum.umd.edu/search?site=UMCP&client=UMCP&proxystylesheet=UMCP&output=xml_no_dtd&as_oq=site%3A&q=Search+UMD.edu&search+button=Search&username=???&password=???> (referer: http://go.galegroup.com.proxy-um.researchport.umd.edu/ps/eToc.do?docId=0PQC&userGroupName=umd_um&action=DO_BROWSE_ETOC&inPS=true&prodId=GVRL&etocId=GALE%7CCX2830999001&isDownLoadOptionDisabled=true)
2017-10-14 09:13:33 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2017-10-14 09:13:33 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 1268,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/POST': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 18230,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 14, 14, 13, 33, 929932),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 3,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'memusage/max': 50655232,
 'memusage/startup': 50655232,
 'request_depth_max': 1,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 3,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 3,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 3,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 3,
 'splash/render.html/request_count': 1,
 'splash/render.html/response_count/200': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 14, 14, 13, 32, 187173)}
2017-10-14 09:13:33 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

I can provide the pages that are returned if that would help.

Answer (score 0):

try initial request to your link:
https://login.proxy-um.researchport.umd.edu/login?url=http://go.galegroup.com/ps/eToc.do?docId=0PQC&userGroupName=umd_um&action=DO_BROWSE_ETOC&inPS=true&prodId=GVRL&etocId=GALE|CX2830999001&isDownLoadOptionDisabled=true
and use scrapy.FormRequest.from_response() without any formdata.
After this you will redirect to https://shib.idm.umd.edu/shibboleth-idp/profile/SAML2/POST/SSO?execution=e2s1

Some thing like this:

```
def start_requests(self):
    yield scrapy.Request(self.start_urls[0])

def parse(self, response):
    with open('prepare.html', 'w') as f:
        f.write(response.body)
    return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(response, callback=self.prepare_login)

def prepare_login(self, response):
    with open('login.html', 'w') as f:
        f.write(response.body)
    return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(response, formdata={'username': '???', 'password': '???'},
                                            callback=self.after_login)

def after_login(self, response):
    with open('after_login.html', 'w') as f:
        f.write(response.body)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work. I've moved on to using Selenium to solve my problem but thanks anyway.